# What problems would there be in allowing override extensions in c#

Tags: c#, oop, extension-methods

As per the language specification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

> You can use extension methods to extend a class or interface, but not
>   to override them. An extension method with the same name and signature
>   as an interface or class method will never be called. At compile time,
>   extension methods always have lower priority than instance methods
>   defined in the type itself.

What I don't understand is *why* is there this limitation? *What programming problems would there be in allowing override extensions?*

**A simple case study**

The base class `Object` has a method ToString(), which by default returns the object type name to a string. It could be argued that for all intents and purposes, it is designed to be overridden.

By default a `Stream` does not provide an override to `ToString` as its not know whether converting the bytes to a string would be meaningful.

However, as the programmer of a solution I know all streams are meaningful if converted to strings. However, I don't want to, *or cannot*, derive from stream classes. So, I would like to extend the `ToString` method to convert the stream to a string; like so:

```
public static String ToString(this Stream stream)
{
    var memory = new MemoryStream(); //closable
    var reader = new StreamReader(memory);
    stream.Position = 0;
    stream.CopyTo(memory);
    memory.Position = 0;
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

However, as per the specification this will never be called at run-time. But why be so strict with the limitation in this case? As `Stream` derives from `Object`, should it not mean that any extensions methods specifically for `Stream` should by default override base type methods?

In addition there are cases where simply naming it `AsString` would not be useful; namely WPF which uses `ToString` as a fallback to represent an item.

Comment: It might well be possible - but the reason why the feature isn't there is because, to paraphrase Eric Lippert, *nobody has implemented it yet*. The cost/benefit hasn't justified it (yet). (For more discussion http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx)

Comment: what if you are using a third party library, that uses a derived class of Stream (fictitious class XmlStream), which relies upon the default behaviour of Stream.ToString()? Now that you have modified that behaviour, won't third party code behave differently than expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An extension method is outside of the inheritance hierarchy of the extended object.

The language (and IDE) simply make this **completely separate** class to look like it is part of the extended type.

To allow for overriding, the whole inheritance model and extension mechanism would need to be changed - that is a very large change, probably a breaking one at that.

In short - this is a feature whose implementation costs would outweigh its usefulness.